# Easiest way to detect Production or Dev environment in NextJs?

Tags: next.js

I want to basically detect whether the running environment is dev or production in Nextjs. Is there any straight forward way of doing this?

```js
if(env == "dev"){
  // do something
}
else if (env == "prod"){
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 102):

Yes, this should work out of the box if you access `env` via `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

When you run your application via `next dev` this will be *development*
While building your application and running `next start` sets this variable to *production*.

Therefore this should work:

```js
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
if(env == "development"){
  // do something
}
else if (env == "production"){
 // do something
}
```

Comment: I found this to be not true since client side can't read if you don't name your environment variable starting with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. Or I might be wrong here.

Comment: @choz This of course only works in server code. For client side code you would need to generate a flag and include it there. Personally I would drop the 2nd `if` condition, just to make sure that production code path is always executed when you are not running in development environment

Comment: @choz Next.js 10 magically sets `process.env.NODE_ENV` both server and browser. It ignores the actual  `NODE_ENV` environment variable and decides dev vs prod based on `npm dev` vs `npm start`. This is just a magic case, in general only `NEXT_PUBLIC_`  variables are made available as you say.

Comment: Can a link to documentation be provided for this?

Answer (score 15):

Basically the same solution, but I didn't want to pollute my code with the ugly conditional. So I factored it out into a simple module:

```js
export const inDevEnvironment = !!process && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
```

and now I can just write in server code

```js
import {inDevEnvironment} from '../lib/DevEnv';
...
   <div>
     {inDevEnvironment || /* ... production only code ... */}
   </div>
...
   <div>
     {inDevEnvironment && /* ... development only code ... */}
   </div>
...
```

Comment: Smaller version:
export const isDevEnvironment = process && process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";

Comment: that looks even worse than the conditional

Comment: @timmerz using a booleanic expression, inside of an if statement, to set another boolean, just seems like a code smell.  Just set the boolean to the value of the expression.